# The best way to check if Tab with exact ID exists in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Sometimes there is tab Id stored in a variable and you need to check if tab still exists before doing something with it (because users can close tabs at any time). I've found this solution:

```
chrome.tabs.get(1234567, function(tab) {
  if (typeof tab == 'undefined') {
    console.log('Tab does not exist!');
  }
});
```

It works but it has quite serious disadvantage. It writes error message into console like this:

```
Error during tabs.get: No tab with id: 1234567.
```

And this is not an exception. So try/catch can't help. It's just a message in console.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: This error now looks like

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.get: No tab with id: 1234567.`

Comment: Why not look through the result of `chrome.windows.getAll` instead?

Comment: Instead of checking if it exists, why not explicitly remove that particular `tabId` when the tab is closed. Just listen to the `onRemoved` event.

Comment: Yes it's possible to implement the solution using `onRemoved` but it will not be the simplest. You will need to store the array of IDs somewhere. Where? In background page? So you will need to send messages to background page to know if tab still exists. And you will need to not forget to put IDs of all opened tabs into this array. It's quite cumbersome solution, isn't it?

Comment: The message is not showing in the console anymore. `Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 m`

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyanin The edit to your question is misleading, the error itself can still appear. I suggest to accept anglinb's answer, because that is correct.

Comment: @Rob W ... interesting ... why do you think that it can appear once again in future releases of Chrome? Since Chrome 39 as Deadpool says it has disappeared (I've tested it in Chrome 40 and confirm that it has disappeared). But you have impolitely edited may addition to the question where I've said about this. And BTW I can't accept anglinb's answer now because this error doesn't appear any more independently check you chrome.runtime.lastError or not.

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyanin The error never disappeared in the first place. See http://i.stack.imgur.com/S0U7z.png (40.0.2214.91, also tested in 39.0.2171.96). If that screenshot doesn't convince you, I invite you to read Chromium's source code: https://cs.chromium.org/%22TabsGetFunction::RunSync()%22.

Comment: @RobW hmmm ... yesterday I've checked it but ... ok, I'm sorry. And anglinb is completely right about chrome.runtime.lastError.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
function callback() {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        // Tab exists
    }
}
chrome.tabs.get(1234,callback);
```

source [Chrome Extension error: "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running browserAction.setIcon: No tab with id"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735050/chrome-extension-error-unchecked-runtime-lasterror-while-running-browseraction)

**Edit:**

> Chrome checks if the value of chrome.runtime.lastError was checked in
>   a callback, and outputs a console message for this "unhandled async
>   exception". If you do check it, it won't pollute the console.

From the comment by @Xan

Comment: As far as I can tell, the idea here is that Chrome checks if the value of `chrome.runtime.lastError` was checked in a callback, and outputs a console message for this "unhandled async exception". If you do check it, it won't pollute the console.

Comment: That's exactly right. I will add that to the answer.

Comment: After implementing this fix, sometime I receive "Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: The tab was closed." error in background console. Any idea?

Comment: Note that this works in most cases (including for the question posed here), but not every case. I've received an invalid tab id error in the background page for `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText()` before.

Answer (score 4):

There is another solution based on Ian's comment (thank you @Ian) to the question.

```
function tabExists (tabId, onExists, onNotExists) {
  chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
    for (var i = 0, window; window = windows[i]; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, tab; tab = window.tabs[j]; j++) {
        if (tab.id == tabId) {
          onExists && onExists(tab);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
    onNotExists && onNotExists();
  });
}
```

It is tested and works good so everybody can use it. If somebody can find shorter solution then using `chrome.windows.getAll` please write!

**UPDATE: Since @anglinb's answer this my answer is not actual any more**

Comment: This method is more heavy than a simple `chrome.tabs.get`. If you need to call the method very often, I recommend against the method. If you really hate the original error message, override the `console.error` method to get rid of it. Or use `console.clear();` to wipe the console.

Comment: Override `console.error` just to get rid of single message? This is a joke, I think.

Comment: No, I'm not kidding. You can override the `console.error` method, filter the message and call the original `console.error` method if wanted. This is less expensive than your current method.

Comment: Update to my comment above: You cannot override the `console` used by the internal extension runtime any more.

Comment: @RobW, Why not? What's the solution then to override the global error handler? It's required to solve the problem at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131089/unable-to-check-runtime-lasterror-during-browseraction-setbadgetext#comment78167391_32131089

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite surprised that there's no API to do this simple task. Apart from what @KonstantinSmolyanin suggested above, I came up with this simpler method:

```
function checkTabIDValid(nTabID, callbackDone)
{
    chrome.browserAction.getBadgeText({tabId: nTabID}, function(dummy)
    {
        if(callbackDone)
            callbackDone(!chrome.runtime.lastError);
    });
}
```

Unfortunately it also has to report result asynchronously:

```
checkTabIDValid(tabId, function(res){
    console.log("tab " + (res ? "exists" : "doesn't exist"));
});
```

Comment: I didn't check it yet but it looks a bit better than my solution.

Comment: @KonstantinSmolyanin: So where you able to check? I'm not trying to outdo you, I just want to find a faster solution than enumerating through all the tabs.

Comment: @c00000fd, getBadgeText is not the only way, I bet there are tons others (eg executeScript). But quite frankly, these workarounds are ugly and pointless since there is `chrome.tabs.get(1234,callback);`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, there is no "exists" function in chrome API...
I've written this code:

```
  var tabID = 551;
  chrome.tabs.query(  {}, function(tabs) {
    for(let i = 0; i<tabs.length; i++){
      if (tabs[i].id === tabID) {
        alert(`Tab ${tabID} exists!`);
        return;
      }
    }
    alert(`No Tab ${tabID} here.`);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution to check if a specific Tab ID is present:

```
var tabID = 111;
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
    if (tabs.some(tab => tabID == tab.id)) {
      // do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Set a variable before

```
lastRemoved=tab.id;
chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
```

And check it after

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId){
    if(lastRemoved==tabId) return;
    chrome.tabs.get(tabId,
    //...
```

Comment: If tab is closed by user then `lastRemoved` will be undefined.

Comment: Then there'll be no error: "no tab with id..."
Anyway, you can use `onRemoved` to set the variable.

Comment: Or not use the variable. Just control creating/removing tabs. The problem begins when you get wrong id from listener (onUpdated)