# Unable to check runtime.lastError during browserAction.setBadgeText

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[`chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText(object details)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setBadgeText) is used to set the badge text for a chrome extension. However, if the tabId doesn't exist, Chrome produces the following error using `console.error()`:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running browserAction.setBadgeText: No tab with id: ####.

This becomes a problem when the badge text is set during a page load. If the tab originally exists but is closed by the user, `setBadgeText` ends up being called using a non-existent `tabId`.

Normally, this can just be prevented by checking `chrome.runtime.lastError` in the callback argument of the problematic function [as was answered in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25736436/3150271). However, since `browserAction.setBadgeText()` has no callback parameter, there seems to be no way to prevent the error.

When `tabId` is an integer not representing any tab, the following code still produces the error even though it attempts to...

- catch the error with `try...catch` *(which doesn't work since `console.error()` is not thrown)*.
- check `lastError` after calling `setBadgeText` *(which doesn't work since the function is asynchronous)*.
- use various `setTimeout` intervals to check `lastError` after calling `setBadgeText` *(which doesn't work and probably wouldn't be reliable)*.
- add a callback argument to `setBadgeText` *(which has been commented out since chrome produces another error when using it since there is no second argument)*.

```
var tabId = 5000;
function clearError () {
    console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
}
try {
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
        text: 'text',
        tabId: tabId
    }/*, clearError*/);
    clearError();
    setTimeout(clearError, 0);
    setTimeout(clearError, 50);
    setTimeout(clearError, 500);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught', e);
    clearError();
}
```

Would there be any way to properly check `chrome.runtime.lastError` to prevent this error from occurring?

Comment: This actually seems to be a bug in Chrome (the fact that `lastError` assumes that a callback exists, but the signature does not allow for it). You should report it.

Comment: ..and if you do report it, you should link to the issue here.

Comment: Did they solve this bug yet? There needs to be a handler for setBadgeText if it's gonna set lastError!

Comment: @Xan, On the other hand, isn't there a way to hook into the "global" error handler for the Chrome extension?

Comment: Hooking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571393/the-best-way-to-check-if-tab-with-exact-id-exists-in-chrome/25831100#comment27755699_16572307

Comment: @Pacerier No they didn't. Thanks for the reminder though. I meant to post an answer with the bug report.

Comment: Note that starting with Chrome 67 you should be able to use a callback to catch errors. At least this was the reply I got after [reporting this issue](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/chromium-extensions/nAk_Hlkv46o/4UiwZkcmCAAJ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option would be to call [chrome.tabs.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-get) first and if no error is called assume that the tab will exist for the next few milliseconds.

```
var tabId = 5000;
function callback(tab) {
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
    } else {
        chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
            text: 'text',
            tabId: tabId
        });
    }
}
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, callback);
```

There is of course always a chance the tab could get closed between `tabs.get` finishing and `setBadgeText` getting called but it's very unlikely.

Comment: Very true. I would think this would have the same error, but I have yet to see it again.

Comment: Isn't there a way to hook into the "global" error handler for the Chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `chrome.tabs.get()` as described above, you can also piggyback off an existing browserAction method that accepts a callback to catch for errors. Example:

```
var tabId = 5000;
chrome.browserAction.getTitle({tabId: tabId}, function(result) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) return;
  // The coast is clear...
  chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({
    text: 'text',
    tabId: tabId
  });
});
```

Good news: `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText()` should also support a callback function like `chrome.browserAction.getTitle()` starting with Chrome 67 according to [one source](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-extensions/nAk_Hlkv46o/4UiwZkcmCAAJ). Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 0):

A bug was reported for this issue and has been marked as fixed: https://crbug.com/451320